# How to make Office Web App Server able to edit a document with Cobalt

Tags: asp.net-web-api, office365, ms-wopi, fsshttp

I am trying to build my own WOPI host using ASP.NET MVC and its WebAPI functions according to this example

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Building-an-Office-Web-f98650d6

I successfully used that example to connect to my Office Web App Server and I can use that to access files of Excel and PowerPoint in local path and I am able to edit it, but I cannot use it to open word document in editing mode as the Post action handler isn't implemented completely without any response so that it cannot handle any edit request.

In order to add support for editing of Office document, I tried this example with POST request handler based on Cobalt library extracted from Office Web App Server.

https://github.com/marx-yu/WopiHost

With this example I managed to edit ans save all kinds of document with Office   Web App Server. However, when I tried to integrate these two together I found that even if I can enter the edit window of Excel and PowerPoint and I can see that Post Requests from Office Web App Server like locking and Cobalt are handled by my WOPI Post API action handler. Those change doesn't take any effect on my local file at all. Moreover, I still cannot edit word document and when I checked the back log of Office Web App Server, I found the error message is Cobalt is not supported while I have already set the SupportsCobalt in CheckFileInfo response to true! Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have exactly what you are looking for. Check out my [implementation of the WOPI host](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost). It's an MVC6 app that takes the best from the both examples you are referring to and adds some extra features.